# magento 2.2.8: mail attachment not working

Tags: error, send-mail, magento2.2.8, attachment

I have installed email attachment extension https://github.com/manishjoy1993/email-attachment  in magento 2.2.8 version and it throw some errors. Errors mentioned in following image.
And there are some solutions available on internet but they are for 2.3.x version but I have installed 2.2.8

In magneto 2.2.8,it throw following error
[image]

I also installed magento 2.2.3 version,for this I have applied code from webkul

https://webkul.com/blog/attach-pdf-file-magento-2-email/
 This webkul link works fine in 2.2.3 but not in magento 2.2.8

Comment: run setup:di:compile and error will gone

Comment: @niraj patel have you tried with ramkrishna suggestion? max problem will solve please let me know if still issue facing?

Comment: But I have installed magento 2.2.8 in xampp in my local machine ,so it throws allow memory size error in cmd  when I run setup:di:compile so  I have to increase memory size for that

Comment: @NagarajuKasa still facing same error

Comment: php -d set_time_limit=3600 -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Use this command and let me know if you still facing the same issue?

Comment: I used this command ,it ran successfully but same email error occurred

Comment: rm -rf generation/ then try again should work for you

Comment: Whenever I got this type of error like interceptor, so first I delete generation folder when I got this error I removed generation folder but no luck so I am deleting whole instance and install again magento 2.2.8 version then I will let you know

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I installed again but same error I don’t know what issue happening ?